# Git Version Control in Emacs Code Browser

Tags: git, emacs, emacs-ecb

I recently installed emacs code browser and noticed that CVS is integrated into it. Can ecb configured to use git as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember about CVS-specific support in ECB, so I'll try to answer about generic Git support.

Emacs VCS should support Git out of box - you can read about VC in official documentation or in [my article about VC](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsVC.html).  There is also [DVC package](http://download.gna.org/dvc/), that is designed to work with different distributed version control systems and have slightly more features than VC (you can find more details in its manual or in [this article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsDVC.html)).

Although the best package for Git is [magit](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/) - it support most of Git's commands, and have extended features, comparing to VC and DVC packages.  There are also other Git-related packages, I described them (and also magit) in [other my article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/EmacsGit.html).

P.S. all these articles are parts of big [article about version control in Emacs](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-vcs/), that describes many other version control systems.

Comment: There are version control icons in ECB when you're using CVS, so I guess that's what @morej is asking about.

Comment: I'll try to check, although ECB isn't working with fresh CEDET on my current machine

Comment: ECB is poorly maintained for some time now. That ultimately made me stop using it.

Comment: @Bozhidar: I was referring to the icons as well as the fact in ECB when I right-click a directory, within the `version control` menu I only see CVS options i.e. `cvs status` `cvs examine` `cvs update`. Since you no longer use ECB, what do you use instead?

Comment: It's better to use `Version control` submenu from `Tools` menu - it provides access to VC commands that will work with any supported VCS

Comment: @morej: I use emacs-nav + imenu + etags + magit . It's not exactly the same, but it works ok for me.